# Fast Distributed Memory Access in C#

Tags: c#, shared-memory, tcplistener, inter-process-communicat

I have a C# WCF service that hosts 120 GB of memory in a `Dictionary<File,byte[]>` for very fast access of file contents, which really worked well with me. Upon access, the file contents were wrapped within a MemoryStream and read

This service needs to be restarted everyday to load some static data from the database that could change on daily basis. The restart took so much time because of the huge data that need to be loaded again into memory

So I decided to host this memory in a different process on the same machine, and access it through sockets. The Data process will be always up and running. TcpListener/Client and NetworkStream were used in a similar fashion to the following

```
memoryStream.Read(position.PositionData, 0, position.SizeOfData);

position.NetworkStream.Write(position.PositionData, 0, position.SizeOfData);
```

Problem is: this was 10 times slower than hosting the memory in the same process. Slowdown is expected, but a factor of 10 is too much.

I thought of MemoryMappedFiles, but those are more useful for random access to a specific view of the file. My file access is sequential from the beginning all the way to the end.

Is there a different technology or library that could be used in my case? or is this just so expected?

Comment: Can't you read the static data from the database without restarting the service?

Comment: The decision of using TCP on local machine is wrong. You should use named pipes when doing IPC locally.
The answer of nair is correct, you should not do any restart of service. You should have some monitoring logic that just updates whatever you need from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using SQLServer. If so, [Service Broker & SQLNotificaiton](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_service_broker/archive/2008/07/09/real-time-data-integration-with-service-broker-and-other-sql-techniques.aspx) Or [Query notification](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0605061) may be of your friends here. I presume, you need more of a push messaging model, which automatically propagate changes back to service (if something change in db). Therefore, avoid restarting memory/resource intensive  process hence no need to remap your heavy weight dictionary.